# Why is log4j2 logger definition lengthy?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

i am upgrading from log4j to log4j2 and new to log4j in general. I am  finding it difficult to introduce lengthy loggers for every class file in the log4j2.properties file. For instance, if i had to create a new logger in log4j, it would be as simple as introducing a single line in the log4j.properties file compared to a whole block of properties against the same logger.

Ex:- If i have to add a logger for a class2 in package A, i would simply add it as follows :-

```
log4j.logger.A.Class1= DEBUG,file
log4j.logger.A.Class2 = DEBUG,file.
```

I can easily add another logger by simply introducing a third line in the log4j.properties file.
Whereas, if i have to do the same thing, i would have to add the loggers as below :-

```
loggers=file1,file2
logger.file1.name=A.Class1
logger.file1.level = debug
logger.file1.appenderRefs = file
logger.file1.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

logger.file2.name=A.Class2
logger.file2.level = debug
logger.file2.appenderRefs = file
logger.file2.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
```

So, if i have 100 classes the log4j2.properties file would be quite lengthy. Unlike if i had to do the same thing in log4j. Please note the prefix of file1, file2, etc.
Question is, is there a way i can write the logger the same way as i did in log4j? Or, is there a simpler way to achieve the same?

If above is not possible, i might as well stick to log4j. Cause it becomes a serious trouble for me to create loggers for each class in large projects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Log4J2 XML configuration file format with which it will suffice to add one single line to configure logging for a class. This provided that you are content with writing all the log to one and the same destination, otherwise more than one line per class may be required.
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %-30C - %m%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="se.ivankrizsan.java.MyClass" level="DEBUG"/>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>

        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Note also that you can specify the log-level for entire packages and thus multiple classes at once as with the org.springframework package in the above example.

Reference: [Log4J2 XML configuration documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XML).

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I have tried your suggestion, however the logs did not get generated.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="STDOUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %-30C - %m%n" />
        </Console>
  <File name="LOGFILE" target="logs/applog.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %-30C - %m%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="A.class1" level="DEBUG"/>
        <Logger name="A.class2" level="DEBUG"/>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="LOGFILE" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

Comment: Ok, i found the issue. In LOGFILE appender, instead of target="logs/applog.log", we must have fileName="logs/applog.log".

Comment: One final question. Can i presume the <Root> as the default logger? i.e. in my observation it seems to be logging everything else at the level specified in its <Root level="ERROR"> say.